# Compositing Shadow pass problem

Tags: node-editor, shadows, artifacts

Here is my problem, I need to create 2D aspect animation from 3D model in blender.
From the start my rended image is ok[image]

But when I transform it, I need to use the Shadow Pass and 
it looks realy blocky !
Need some help please :)
[image]

Comment: Which render engine did you use?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for jagged shadows lies in the **technique used for rendering the shadows**.
I assume you used the blender internal render engine and the standard shadow of the lamp; for spots lamps the default is the buffered shadow.

### Here is a rough explanation how buffer shadows are calculated

With buffer shadows something like a render is made from the view of the light source lamp. Every surface point not visible on this lamp-rendered image isn't reachable by this light source. Thus, these pixels of the lamp-rendered image projected to the unreachable surfaces will be a good approximation of the shadow in the final render. According to this the blockyness depends on the resolution of this lamp-rendered image. It can be adjusted at the lamp settings:

[image: enlarging the buffer size]

[Here is more info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/lighting/lamps/spot/buffered_shadow.html?highlight=buffer%20shadow) on how the buffering works.

### So increasing the size is the solution?

No. A better way is to change the shadow rendering technique. The other one available in blender internal is `Ray Shadow` which probably is the best solution.
[image: change to Ray shadow]

I hope your shadow pass is blockless with this method now :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It's ok, I have solved this problem using Diffuse too !

Comment: Hi. Please add some extra information as to how you specifically solved this. At the moment this answer doesn't give much information.